# Track invocations of methods and functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, profiling, python-decorators, proxy-object

I'm looking for the library which allows to track invocation of methods and functions. Think of it as of [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.called) providing `called` and `call_count` properties.

Example of end-result needed:

```py
s = MagicProxyLib()

@s
class MyClass:

    def not_called(self):
        print("This is not called")

    def first_method(self):
        print("First is called")

    def second_method(self):
        print("Second is called")


mc = MyClass()
mc.first_method()
mc.second_method()
mc.second_method()
```

I can implement such a decorator myself, but do not want reinvent the wheel if there is already some library with similar functionality.

I expect to be able to use this library is a such way

```py
assert not s.called(mc.not_called)
assert s.called(mc.first_method)
assert s.call_count(mc.second_method) == 2
```

I have checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581254/tracking-number-of-executions-of-methods-and-functions-in-python-package) but profiling/tracing does not quite serve the same purpose as here. Thanks for you package suggestions.

Comment: P.S. I'm aware this can be implemented as a decorator like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716940/is-there-a-way-to-track-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-called, but I'm looking for existing libraries with broader functionality and providing extensive statistic (if exists)

Answer (score 1):

You likely want a profiler - they can collect all this usage statistics. A nice one is shipped along with Python - check: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html